# Getting No Retrofit annotation found. (parameter #3) for a callback

Tags: java, android, retrofit2

I'm trying to make a post request with retrofit defining this interface:

```
public interface UploadImageRestClient {

        @POST("uploadimage")
        void postData(@Header("Cookie") String sessionId, @Body JSONObject image,  
    Callback<Response> callback);
        }
```

Which is called like this:

```
 restClient.postData(MapRecintosFragment.sgaUser.getCookieHeader(), json, new Callback<Response>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<Response> response) {
                                       
    
                                    }
               @Override
               public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t) {
        
        
        }
       });
```

And when it executes in runtime, that restClient.postData instruction it fails with the error menioned in the title.

But, honestly, I don't know what Retrofit anotation I am supposed to put to a Callback, it makes no sense to me.

How could I solve this error?

Answer (score 1):

You made mistake at below point

```
    @POST("uploadimage")
    void postData(@Header("Cookie") String sessionId, @Body JSONObject image,  
Callback<Response> callback);
    }
```

it should be like below

```
    @POST("uploadimage")
    Call<Response> postData(@Header("Cookie") String sessionId, @Body JSONObject image);
```

Hope you understand... :)

Comment: @pratikvekarija, still same error.

Comment: remove this "Callback<Response> callback" from postData method (last parameter), i dont think its required

Comment: @user2638180 check edited answer.

Comment: @user2638180 hi, is my answer correct?? then pls make it correct. :)

Answer (score 0):

remove 3# params

```
@POST("uploadimage")
    public Call<ResponseBody> postData(@Header("Cookie") String sessionId, @Body 
        JSONObject image);
    }
```

to Use

```
retrofit.create(UploadImageRestClient.class).postData(MapRecintosFragment.sgaUser.ge 
    tCookieHeader(), json).enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>{
       
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<Response> call, Response<ResponseBody> 
            response){}
        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<Response> call, Throwable t){}
    })
```